# how to set visible = false by knockout

Tags: javascript, html, dom, knockout.js

I have posted more detailed question this is much clear and straightforward
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48327378/8072569)

hello, I am trying to set the value of list element to false by using knockout 
this is my HTML

```
   <li>
     <a onclick="log(this)" data-bind="visible: true, text: $data"></a>
            </li>
```

is there a way to say something like this :

```
               myViewModel.items()[i].setVisible(false);
```

Comment: bind to a property, not `true` directly.

Answer (score 3):

Don't set the visible binding to true set it to the variable you define in your viewModel. Also you can access individual elements of an observable array through the foreach binding.  Lastly, if you want to use $data you can access the property of the individual array object directly using the "." operator. The documentation I referenced at the end of my post has more information. See below:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: shouldShowMessageArray">
    <div data-bind="visible: $data.shouldShowMessage">
        Message goes here.
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var myViewModel;
$(document).ready(function(){
    myViewModel = new viewModel();
    function viewModel() {
        this.shouldShowMessage = ko.observable(false) // Message initially visible
        this.shouldShowMessageArray = ko.observableArray([
            {shouldShowMessage: ko.observable(true)},
            {shouldShowMessage: ko.observable(false)}
        ]);
    }
    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
});
</script>
```

[Knockout foreach / $data documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

Comment: this would work if it was not an array, it's an array so how would you go about hiding an element of the array?

Comment: to make it more clear I am getting the data by using $data,

Comment: Got it. Updated my answer. Basically you can access the property directly from $data.

Comment: what about if I was pushing the element to the array how would you about that? how would I give each element property which is by default a true visible observable, thanks so much

Comment: if you got the time see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/48327378/8072569

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, give me a minute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163444/discussion-between-salmanalharbi-and-jonathan-chaplin).

Comment: @SalmanALharbi I updated my original answer. You should use an observable (ko.observable) and by calling the observable method shouldShowMessage(false); knockout automatically refreshes your display

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to load the page with a starting value of visible:false, you may run into some issues with the "visible" binding.

I have had trouble with the "visible" binding when I want an element to be hidden on page load, and then made visible after some action taken by the user. You will see a flash of the hidden element while your knockout.js logic loads if you are using the visible binding. If you try to use inline CSS to set display:none on the element, then it will **never** become visible even when the KO logic results in a visible:true value. This is because KO applies the CSS rules after it has handled changing the element.style.display value.

One solution to this issue that I have found is to set up a CSS class that well set display to none, and then use a data binding to conditionally apply that CSS rule based on an observable.

CSS:

```
.hideMe { display: none; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="hideContent" data-bind="css: { hideContent: !yourObservable() }">
     <p>Content</p>
</div>
```